# Linq - how to write group by query to get quantity of each product

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello every one I have a data as follows

```
Item    Qty Type
1       2   Purchase
1       3   Sales
1       8   Return

2       5   Purchase
2       4   Sales
2       5   Return
```

Now I have a requirement of getting quantity of each item by Subtracting Sales and Return with Purchase
And my final output would be

```
item    Qty
1      -9
2      -4
```

Note : To get quantity: Qty => (Purchase Qty - SalesQty - Return Qty) eg: (2-3-8)

So how can I write this query on LINQ or in SQL

Comment: So, what have you tried (in code)?

Comment: How does your class structure look like?

Comment: Is your math correct?   Should it be 2-3+8=7?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Item, SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Purchase' THEN Qty ELSE -Qty END) AS Qty
FROM Table
GROUP BY Item
```

LINQ:

```
Items
.GroupBy(p => p.Item)
.Select(p => new
{
     Item = p.Key,
     Qty = p.Sum(x => x.Type == "Purchase" ? x.Qty : -x.Qty)
});
```

Comment: Will this query able to subtract those three values. I mean this  (Purchase Qty - SalesQty - Return Qty)

Comment: @ChrisHadfield It will get what you're looking for. Test it and see the results

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ to SQL, you can do:

```
var ans = from i in src
          group i by i.Item into ig
          let PurchaseQty = ig.Where(i => i.Type == "Purchase").Sum(i => i.Qty)
          let SalesQty = ig.Where(i => i.Type == "Sales").Sum(i => i.Qty)
          let ReturnQty = ig.Where(i => i.Type == "Return").Sum(i => i.Qty)
          select new {
              Item = ig.Key,
              Qty = PurchaseQty - SalesQty - ReturnQty
          };
```

If you are using LINQ to EF 2.2, it may work but will do the grouping client side. If you are using EF 3.x, good luck!